# Name of operation over bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, terminology, book-recommendation

Given a bipartite graph $G_0=(V_1\cup V_2, E_0),$ I want to build another graph $G_1=(V_1,E_1)$, where its edges are defined from the part $V_2$, in this way:
$$ E_1=\{(v_1,v_2): v_1,v_2\in V_1 \text{ and they share a neighbor}\}$$

A picture for reference, notice the colors of the edges.

[image]

This can be seen as a projection over the incidence matrix, also one can do the same operation but on the other part of $G$, i want to know what properties the resulting graphs, $G_1$ and $G_2$, have.

I don't think I'm the first person to think of this so I hope to find some background, reference material or keywords.
Thanks!

Comment: In very general terms you are taking the square of your graph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_power (and then restricting the result to the subgraph induced on one or the other side).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as a [bipartite half](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_half) or half-square of a graph.

(In general, one notion of the square $G^2$ of a graph $G$ is the graph on the same vertex set with an edge whenever two vertices are at most distance $2$ apart in $G$; if we take the square of a bipartite graph, and then take the subgraph induced by one part, we get the half-square.)

It is also not uncommon to go from a bipartite graph to the hypergraph with vertex set $V_1$ where, for every vertex in $V_2$, we add a hyperedge through all of its neighbors.

Answer (score 1):

In graph theory, this operation is also called a projection.  Wikipedia has an article on [bipartite network projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_network_projection), but it generalizes to multipartite networks.